# Why don't we lain the Makkos on Pesach?

Tags: passover, torah-reading

There are several portions in the Torah that discuss Pesach, and we lain most (if not all) of them on Pesach, plus the actual story of Kriyas Yam Suf. Why don't we, in a similar vein, read the Makkos which were also an integral part of yetziyas Mitzrayim?

Comment: They didn't happen on pesach?